# different methods in passing parameters in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using cakephp v1.26.
I got a function in a controller like this:

```
class testingsController extends AppController{

function testing($id=null){
$recieved = $id;}

}
```

I am not sure if there are any better ways to pass a parameter to the Action testing.
But I have come across some web sites and got these two methods.
Is there any difference in the following parameter passing methods?

```
1. url/testings/testing/1
2. url/testings/testing:1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `url/testings/testing/1`

With standard routes, this will call `TestingsController::testing(1)`.

This is standard parameter passing, any parameters beyond `/:controller/:action/` are passed "as-is" to the called action.

`/controllers/action/param1/param2` corresponds to
`ControllersController::action($param1, $param2)`

> `url/testings/testing:1`

With standard routes, this will call `TestingsController::index()` and
set `$this->params['named']['testing']` to `1`. This is known as a named parameter.

Named parameters can be passed in any order. These two URLs are equivalent:
`url/testings/testing:1/foo:2`
`url/testings/foo:2/testing:1`

They will **not** be passed to the function, as in `function testing($id = null)`. `$id` will be `null`. They're only available in the `$this->params['named']` array.

Comment: Yes, a far more verbose answer than mine, and I'd forgotten [named]! Shame on me ;)

Answer (score 1):

The first example you have will pass it as a numeric parameter

```
$this->params[0]; // 1
```

The second will pass a named pair, rather like an array

```
$this->params['testing']; // 1
```

You can use either for different things. You'll notice that the paginator uses `key:val` paired parameters when sorting columns and pages.

There is a little bit of further info in the Book, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passed-arguments